# Additional claims not showing up on cognito ID token

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito, aws-sam

I am using a following CloudFormention Template to add `cognito:preferred_role` claim to my ID token.

```
IdentityPoolRoleAttachment: 
  Type: AWS::Cognito::IdentityPoolRoleAttachment 
  Properties: 
    IdentityPoolId: !Ref IdentityPool
    Roles: 
      "authenticated": !GetAtt AuthenticatedRole.Arn 
      "unauthenticated": !GetAtt UnAuthenticatedRole.Arn 
    RoleMappings:  
      　"userpool1": 
           IdentityProvider: !Join …
           AmbiguousRoleResolution: Deny 
           Type: Token
```

But I recieved an ID token only contains standard claims on my client app.

I also noticed unauthenticated role is applyed to a user after login.

I changed `AmbiguousRoleResolution` to `AuthenticatedRole` but still no additional claims.
What I am missing to do?

I need to send this token to an api gateway to assume role base on `cognito:roles` or  `cognito:preferred_role` claim to call dynamo sdk using authenticated role on lambda.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the question? You're talking about ID tokens, which implies a User Pool, but the CFN template that you've shared only describes a part of an Identity pool. As far as I understand the question, I also don't see the need for an Identity pool, since you are only communicating with an API gateway, and not an AWS resource directly. So either I'm not understanding the question fully, or you seems to have confused two different things in Cognito.